# Why variable len value not changing in db transaction?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, android-sqlite

```
    //this is constructor of my code
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        textValue:this.getFavoritesLength(),
        };
    }
```

//this sqlite code db.transaction execute prefect but it not changing the value of var len it always returns 0 while i  changing the   value of len as table length.

```
getFavoritesLength()
{
    var len = 0;
    db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql(
            'SELECT * FROM table_favorites', [],
            (tx, results) => {
                len = results.rows.length;
                console.log('select * results are = ', len);
                // if (len > 0) {
                //   return len;
                // }else{
                //   return 0;
                // }
            }
        );
    });
    return len;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while running a query it does not provide the response instantly. Execution of query takes some time and give the response in the callback function.
Can you try using async

```
insertarDatos = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.transaction((tx) => {
        try {
          /* Successful transaction */
          /* Make sure to call resolve when the transaction has finished, maybe 
             db.transaction has a success callback
          */
          resolve()
        } catch (error) {
          /* Failed transaction */
          // if you reject any eventual errors, you can catch them when calling the function insertarDatos

          reject(error)
        }
      });
    })
  }
```

Comment: i just wants to return the length of table

Comment: objects are not valid as a react child (found object with keys _u _v _w _x )

Comment: can you modify my getFavoritesLength() method